# meioupload and updates

Tags: cakephp

I am using meioupload to upload images into my cakephp website, it works great on add but update is deleting the image. Can somebody help me understand the correct way to use this component for updates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check the validations

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm having the same problem.